# does cost function of one hidden layer perception have only one global minimal

Tags: gradient-descent

is it true that:

After training a multilayer perceptron with one hidden layer using gradient descent, we always
get the same decision boundary regardless of the initialization point.

Comment: The titular question does not match the text in the question itself.

Comment: I thought that the two are equivalent?

Comment: Sorry, let me elaborate. A function can have a single global minimum, but that does not exclude the possibility of local minima or [saddle points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/279094). Hence, having a global minimum does not mean your optimizer will reach it irrespective of the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

NO.

With one hidden layer, the objective function is not convex (even for squared loss in regression). Therefore, we may have many local minima instead of one global minima.

Using gradient decent and where to end, will depend on the initialization point.

Comment: why is the cost function not convex?